# Finding inverse series

Tags: statistics

Let $X$ be discrete random variable and its characteristic function is

$$\varphi(t)=\left(\frac{1}{3}e^{it}+\frac{2}{3}\right)^{10} $$

Then, PDF=?

or; if

$$\sum_{x} e^{itx}p(x)=\left(\frac{1}{3}e^{it}+\frac{2}{3}\right)^{10}$$

then $p(x) = ?$

Are there any methods for finding this PDF? ( inverse series ? (as inverse Fourier Series) )

Comment: Welcome to MSE. In order to get useful answers to your questions you should show your own work.

Comment: @Edu: Show _what_ 'work'? Either you recognize it or you don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, there is no 'inversion' formula to get from MGF (Laplace transform) to PDF. (By contrast, there is an inversion formula to get from what statisticians/probabilists call a 'characteristic function' (Fourier transform) to CDF.)

However, your MGF is that of a binomial distribution. 
Specifically, $\mathsf{Binom}(n=10,\,p=1/3).$
The partial "inversion formula" for MGF's is to have seen enough of them to recognize
the most common ones.